# refer to second function output in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For a project I have a list of possible activation functions to choose from, depending on whats chosen in the configuration.
i want these to all be g() so that g is a changeable function.
Also in each function file, i have defined the derivative as a function Dg():

```
function [g Dg]  = identity(x)
g  = x;
Dg = 1
end
```

I can refer to the first output of the function:

```
g = @identity
```

but how do i define Dg() in a similar way?

Comment: The `@` symbol forms a handle to either the named function that follows the `@` sign, or to the anonymous function that follows the `@` sign. `g=@identify` does not give you the first output but gives your function `identify` another name `g` so you can use it as `[g Dg] = g(x)`. Read more [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html).

Comment: Honestly, I can read the question in 5 different ways ... and I see answers trying to answer different things. Try to explain a bit more explicitely what is it you want to achieve or to get as output, and also please **do not reuse symbols names in the same code snipet** (your `g` variable is used in different places with the same name while they are completely different variables with different scopes).

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong, you are not referring to the first output of the function, you are referring to the entire function like that. in your example, `g` *becomes* `identity`.

You can test this by doing:

```
g = @identity;
[out1,out2]=g(5)
```

You can rename it as much as you want

```
mrpotato = @identity;
[out1,out2]=mrpotato(5)
```

Possibly the fact that when you call a function without brackets in the output it only returns 1 output and in conjunction you named the function the same as the first output mislead you to think you are catching the first output, but this is not the case, you are just copying the entire function and calling it `g`

`@` is an operator to define/reference functions.

Comment: It's not a solution. the question is how to "refer to second function output in MATLAB".

Comment: @OmG what do you mean? I literally show how to do it :/. The proposition of the problem was wrong, that needed to be tackled.

Comment: He wanna refer to the second output as a function! not to get the result of the `identity` function after applying the identity on a value. Something like `@Dg`. You know.

Comment: @OmG that would be the case, with a different wording. I am here interpreting that OP thinks that their `g` is the first output, and it plainly is not. So the premise is wrong, as they are not doing what they think they are, therefore their objective (`@Dg`) comes from  a derivative logic from a flawed proposition. I am pointing that out. Defining `Dg()` in a similar way to `g` is doing `Dg=g`, but I am sure that is not what OP thought.

Comment: I see. But the OP wants to refer to the outputs as a function and your explanation does not solve his problem at all. Indeed, you are explaining his fault to refer to the first output as a function. Anyhow, it might be satisfiable for the OP.

Comment: @OmG what OP is asking is flawed and cannot be answered. `Dg` can never be a function or be output as a function handle because it is double... Unless you say `[g Dg]  = identity(x); Dg=@Dg;` but I'm sure MATLAB will throw you an exception. However, if all OP wants is the second output then @AnderBiguri has given him a solution.

Comment: @MikaelWendt yes, I get that. But `g` is not the first output, its both.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to a function with a single output in the expression, such as `a=something();`, will always return the first output of `something()`, whether it is a function or a handle to a function.

A workaround would be to make a function designed to return the second (or n-th) output from whatever handle it is given and pipe *@identity* (or any other handle) through it :

```
function out=take_second_output(fun,input)
    %fun  : function handle
    %input: value
    [~,out]=fun(input);
end

% More generic version,:
% - works with any number of arguments
% - any of the outputs can be picked
%
% Calling 'a=take_nth_output(fun,n,arg1,arg2,...)' is equivalent to
% '[~,~,...(n-1) times ...,a] = fun(arg1,arg2,...)'
function out=take_nth_output(fun,n_out,varargin)
    %fun  : function handle
    %n_out: index of the output to be returned
    out_tmp=cell(n_out,1);
    out_tmp{:} = fun(varargin{:});
    out = out_tmp{n_out};
end

% define function handle d
d = @identity;
% define Dg as an anonymous handle
Dg = @(x) take_second_output(@identity,x);
Dg_generic = @(x) take_nth_output(@identity,2,x);
```

Comment: *function handles are expected to have a single output.* no it is not true. Try `m=@min; [minimum,index]=m([23, 12])`. Otherwise the answer is right, just note that you can however still do `[~,Dg]=g()` in this case

Comment: You are right, this is poorly stated. What I meant is that statement `a = something();` will always return the first output regardless whether *something()* is a function or a handle to a function, and any additional output will be discarded. I'll rephrase that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain functions `g` and `Dg`, you probably want to return function handles instead. Something like this:

```
function [g,Dg] = identity
   g  = @(x) x;
   Dg = @(x) 1;
end
```

Now this line:

```
[g,Dg] = identity;
```

will give you two functions, which you can use as:

```
y = g(x);
dy = Dg(x);
```

A more complicated example, the actual functions returned here are not all that complex, but this shows the mechanics. You can create complicated functions with tunable parameters, flow control, etc.:

```
function [g,Dg] = complicated(scale)
   g  = @func;
   Dg = @deriv_func;

   function y = func(x)
      y = cos*scale(x);
   end
   function y = deriv_func(x)
      y = -scale*sin(scale*x);
   end
end
```

Similarly to before, you now do:

```
[g,Dg] = complicated(4.7);
```

to get your function handles. The 4.7 will be “embedded” in those handles, meaning that it affects the meaning of the functions `g` and `Dg`.